# htaccess rewrite to include #!

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Calling all .htaccess gurus. I need your help!

I'm trying to force a rewrite to include #! in the urls.

So basically I need.
http://example.com/biography

To be re-written to 
http://example.com/#!/biography

If it will make any difference my rewrite rules so far are

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond $1 !^(images|system|files|themes|static|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I suck at this stuff so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Additionally...

I have this test doing what I need it to do in this htaccess tester. http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ But it won't work when I try it on my site...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/#!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#!/$1 [L]
```

No ideas as to why it won't work?

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: dunno if you're allowed to rewrite a url to something with a hash....but could redirecting work for you?

Comment: # in the url is clientside, so you can do that only with a redirect

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have your .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(biography)/?$ /#!/$1 [R,L,NE,NC]

RewriteCond $1 !^(images|system|files|themes|static|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Remember you cannot have a condition to check for `/#!` in .htaccess because that part is handled in browsers only and not sent to web server.

Comment: for the record:  its primarily the flag `[R]` that does the trick - causing a HTTP 302 Redirect and enabling the browser to handle the anchor (the part after `#` which is handled by the client)