# .htaccess rewrite to same alias without infinite redirects

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have...

| **.htaccess** : (v1)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^in?$ login.php
```

So, `/in` --*is-really*--> `/login.php`

This much works great. We all can learn how to do this from: [.htaccess redirect with alias url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653346/htaccess-redirect-with-alias-url)

## But, I want it to also work in reverse...

If someone should enter `/login.php` into the address bar, I want it to change to `/in`.

So also, `/login.php` --*rewrites-to*--> `/in`

From [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72262830/10343144) to a different Question, I want to be ready for anything, using `REQUEST_URI`. So, my `.htaccess` file ***starts*** with this...

| **.htaccess** : (v2)

```
RewriteEngine on

# Remove index.php, if a user adds it to the address
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+/)?index\.php
RewriteRule (^|/)index\.php(/|$) /%1 [R=301,L]

# "in" --> login.php
RewriteRule ^in?$ login.php
```

That also works great.

But now, I want to add this rule (my Question here) for `/in <--> /login.php` both ways, just how `/ <--> /index.php` already works with `.htaccess` (v2). So, I adopted the settings and added a second rule...

| **.htaccess** : (v3) *—not working!*

```
RewriteEngine on

# Remove index.php, if a user adds it to the address
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+/)?index\.php
RewriteRule (^|/)index\.php(/|$) /%1 [R=301,L]

# "in" --> login.php, and also redirect back to it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+/)?login\.php
RewriteRule (^|/)login\.php(/|$) /%1in [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^in?$ login.php
```

...but then `/in` and `/login.php` both cause an infinite redirect loop.

What's the right way to do this, still using `REQUEST_URI`, and still having **both** rewrite rules (for `index.php` and for `login.php`)?

---

These Questions did *not* help:

- [Rewrite rule to hide folder, doesn't work right without trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334289/rewrite-rule-to-hide-folder-doesnt-work-right-without-trailing-slash)

  - This is not about a trailing slash
- [Allow multiple IPs to access Wordpress Site Admin via .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602399/allow-multiple-ips-to-access-wordpress-site-admin-via-htaccess)

  - This is not about IP-based access
- [Htaccess URLs redirects are working for http not all https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205988/htaccess-urls-redirects-are-working-for-http-not-all-https)

  - This is not about `https` vs `http`
- [Rewrite-rules issues : .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904802/rewrite-rules-issues-htaccess)

  - This is not about cleaning up the `GET` array in the URL
- [apache htaccess rewrite with alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334148/apache-htaccess-rewrite-with-alias)

  - This is not about rewriting the host/domain, thereby preserving the path
- [rewrite htaccess causes infinite loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226700/rewrite-htaccess-causes-infinite-loop)

  - This is not about `www` subdomain rewrites
- [.htaccess rewrite page with alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200862/htaccess-rewrite-page-with-alias)

  - This is not about rewriting "pretty" URLs nor about how to use slug settings in WordPress
- [Htaccess alias or rewrite confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674398/htaccess-alias-or-rewrite-confusion)

  - This is not about simply having multiple rules with the same destination
- [htaccess rewrite to include #!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879256/htaccess-rewrite-to-include)

  - I'm not trying to rewrite `#!`

Comment: `but that causes an infinite redirect loop`: Did you try testing in a new browser or from command line `curl`?

Comment: @anubhava Tested many browsers. And, even logically it makes sense, because the code as it does this: Rule 1. `login.php` --> `in`; Rule 2. `in` = `login.php`. So, of course it will infinitely redirect. Is there a `RewriteAlias` option or such way to do this "properly"?

Comment: `of course it will infinitely redirect.` No it won't because after first rewrite to `/login.php` variable `REDIRECT_STATUS` will become `200` and then `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` will stop redirect

Comment: At the gym, I will run some tests based on this later, finding what I overlooked. Good info.

Comment: @anubhava I found that it was other settings that were messing me up. You were right on. I will update my Question so that it includes the full settings file. If you want, you can write the obvious Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason of redirect loop is a missing `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` before first redirect rule that removes `index.php`. Remember that `RewriteCond` is applicable to immediate next `RewriteRule` only.

Suggested .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine on

# Remove index.php, if a user adds it to the address
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+/)?index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

# "in" --> login.php, and also redirect back to it
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+/)?login\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1in [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^in?$ login.php [L,NC]
```

It won't cause redirect loop because after first rewrite to `/login.php`, variable `REDIRECT_STATUS` will become `200` and then the `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` will stop redirect looping.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, but fixed it, for `.htaccess` (v3)  The "index.php" group wrongly had "login.php" in it. It was trying to have BOTH rules, but the second without the `ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS` setting that made the loop. Could you kindly add that *`# Remove index.php...`* group to the answer so it has both rules? Not to boss, it was my mistake with v3. tysm.

Comment: Sure thing, it is updated now.

Comment: That's it! This saves me. So surprised this is actually a new Question. 1,000 Beremie points.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help from the user with the correct answer, I found that...

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
```

...doesn't go in `.htaccess` only once, but every time on the line before...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ...
```